# Is there a website that has a quiz on the entire mesechta? I'm trying to find one so I can quiz myself on the complete Gemara

Tags: talmud-gemara

I need to find a quiz that tests you on an entire mesechta of Gemara.

Comment: I'm leading an Amud Yomi Chaburah on Megillah for which I make a five question quiz on each Amud, but not sure that will help so much...

Comment: For brachos here is one https://dafyomi.co.il/section.php?gid=1&sid=8.  Dirshu gives tests on daf yomi and have completed a cycle. It’s not online but if you can get in touch with them, perhaps they can give it to you

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Daf hashavuah has masechta tests I believe up to megillah

Comment: https://dafyomi.co.il/new_gemara_picker.php
You can navigate to the daf you want, then click "Daily Quiz"
After you finish the quiz, you can press the arrow on the bottom of the screen near the "Index" button to go the next daf's quiz.
If that button doesn't work, just change the number at the end of the URL.